# Copying data from spreadsheet to another and to an active cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hope you guys are able to help me. I have been googling my eyes off...
I'm trying to copy data from one cell (B2) to another spreadsheet (the spreadsheet in use of course). I get the data, but it goes to cell A1 every time.

The cell that I copy the data to will be moving right every week, that is why I can't use a fixed cell.

Here is the code:

```
function a(){

var test = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mysourcespreadsheet").
  getSheetByName("mysourcesheet").getRange("B2").getValues();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell();

cell.setValue(test);
}
```

The thing I really wanted to do is to copy the variable 'test' to the first empty cell in row 4, but let's just take on step at the time as I'm fairly new to the google scripts :)

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you want? I think that this will help users think of about your issue and solution.

Comment: Not sure if this is a correct way to share a spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_5_2s56iOOcu_SkmSA-HcpzX3tbRfjTha78xK0kwYQQ/edit?usp=sharing , I also added comments in the spreadsheet to help you understand the issue

Comment: If it can't find current active cell it'll choose A1 cell by default. Try actually selecting a cell by going to target sheet and then run the function. Also try `sheet.getActiveRange()` instead of `sheet.getCurrentCell()`.

Comment: I tried selecting a cell, but it doesn't help. Neither does the sheet.getActiveRange(), which was my first guess building up the code.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaargh... My stupidity hurts so much! I think I found the error. `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];` -> should be `var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();`

Thanks for the help thou